# Rails 4 : Validate fields from form without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to validate a form but I don't want to use validations from model, because fields come from many models.

I'd like to do something like request from Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921623/how-to-validate-request-parameters-in-rails-4-like-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ActiveModel::Validations** like this

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true
end
```

It will act as a normal model.